# Clojure: returning the whole item, not a destructured value from it, using some

Tags: clojure

I have the following data.

```
(def food-journal
  [{:month 1 :day 1 :human 5.3 :critter 2.3}
   {:month 1 :day 2 :human 5.1 :critter 2.0}
   {:month 2 :day 1 :human 4.9 :critter 2.1}
   {:month 2 :day 2 :human 5.0 :critter 2.5}
   {:month 3 :day 1 :human 4.2 :critter 3.3}
   {:month 3 :day 2 :human 4.0 :critter 3.8}
   {:month 4 :day 1 :human 3.7 :critter 3.9}
   {:month 4 :day 2 :human 3.7 :critter 3.6}])
```

I do not understand why is the following code returning a line only (which is what i want),

```
(some #(and (> (:critter %) 3) %) food-journal)
```

whereas the following code (which I believe to be exactly identical as above) returns a number.

```
(some (fn [{c :critter}] (and (> c 3) c)) food-journal)
```

**Question:** What have I done wrong in the code using the anonymous function `fn` ? Why is it returning a line ? How can I make it return a line of result while preserving `fn`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value of `some` is *the result of running the given function* on the first item for which doing so returns a truthy value. Because it's the function's result, the returned value can differ from the input, as you're seeing here.

---

In the case of

```
(some #(and (> (:critter %) 3) %) food-journal)
```

your `%` refers to the entire map.

---

In the case of

```
(some (fn [{c :critter}] (and (> c 3) c)) food-journal)
```

...you're destructuring the map, and binding `c` only to the `critter` value, not to the entire map. Thus, when you return `c`, you get only the integer value out.

---

Compare that to:

```
(some (fn [{c :critter :as critter-map}]
         (and (> c 3) critter-map))
 food-journal)
```

...which compares only `c` (the destructured number) when deciding to return anything, but when it does decide to return something, returns the entire `critter-map`.

---

Or, instead of using `some`, think of using `filter` to get a lazy sequence, and `first` to take only the first element -- unlike `some`, `filter` returns the item for which the filter returns a truthy value, rather than the truthy value returned:

```
(->> food-journal
  (filter (fn [{c :critter}] (> c 3)))
  (first))
```